# .htaccess fake files and directorys

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to use .htaccess to show /index.php?page=$1 when the file/directory doesn't exist

so `example.com/Something`

would not redirect to, but show `example.com/index.php?page=Something`

same thing for `example.com/Something/SomethingElse`

which should show `example.com/index.php?page=Something/SomethingElse`

Here is my current code, but it isn't working:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}`

See if that works?

Comment: It works partially, although page slowly is extremely slow, it takes 3 seconds longer. EDIT: Also, it doesn't work for directories (ex "Something/SomethingElse")